# Adding context path to SLF4J log statements

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, slf4j

I have multiple Spring webapps deployed in single tomcat, and logging the error messages in single log file. I need to log the context path of the webapp to which the request was hit. 
Currently I have to implement a servlet filter so that the variable value is set for each request. This has to be done because MDC instance is per thread.

***As the context path is constant for the application, is there any way to set the MDC variable only once?***

```
log4j.appender.LOGFILE.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %X{applicationId} %-5p %c - %m%n
```

To set the `applicationId` in MDC I have defined a Servlet Filter

```
public class LogFilter implements Filter {

  @Override
  public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
      throws IOException, ServletException {
    MDC.put("applicationId", request.getServletContext().getContextPath());
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't find any other way, so the code mentioned in the question seems to be the only option. Closing the thread.